# Difference between algorithm time - Classifying a table

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to make a program that classify a vector using 2 different algorithms: Quick (which is O(NlogN)) and Bubble (which is O(N²)). Furthermore, I need to calculate the "delay time" of each algorithm. Since the user can select the method, my program have the following code:

```
 switch(answer[1]){
                case 'L': 
                 start_t = clock()/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                 Log(Tab, NReg-1, answer[0]);
                 end_t = clock()/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                 break;
                case 'Q':
                     start_t = clock()/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                 Quad(Tab, NReg-1, answer[0]);
                 end_t = clock()/ (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                 break;
                 }


    total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) ;
   printf("Time: %f\n", total_t  );
```

Log is the function that call my quick sort algorithm and Quad, Bubble Sort.

But, when I run my program and choose the method that I want to apply, I am getting bigger time on log method than quadratic method. Here, an example of times, in second, for a table with 1000 elements:

Quadratic: 0.0059300

Logarithm: 0.0340000

A bigger different can be noted using a table with more elements. 
Well, we could think that my logarithm method was not efficient. But lets see what happens when I eliminate the previous part of the code and do not give the option for the user to choose the method (that is, I will classify the table using both methods):

Logarithm: 0.5810000

Quadratic: 1,0680000

Well, I don't know what is happening and I have no idea what could be causing this.

Giving a little more information about my program: It reads an archieve with a list of elements and classify it according the method (and field) required by the user. The algorithms are working really well, nothing seems wrong with then for me.

If more information is needed, I will be happy to give it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Typo: The complexity for Quicksort is O(nlogn). Also, have you tried this out for a larger data set, maybe 10,000 elements.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix it. Using more data, I noted that if I run the program, call method Q, I get something like 2 seconds (with 5000 elements). When I call L, it really gives me a little time. But, when I try to use Quick to classify, then bubble (or bubble then quick), the times diverges. I didn't mention, but my program is on loop and I copy the original table (without ordenation) each time I need to classify it using another method or field.

Comment: Could you paste the code of your algorithms?